# Is my asynchronous callback processing implemented safely? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I'm not new to the concept of asynchronous callbacks, but most of my experience is in C#. I'm very new to javascript. I am concerned that what I have done here may be dangerous and I'd appreciate your advice.

What I'm trying to do - call Google Insights API for all locations in a given account. Google allows batches of 10 locations per call. Since I don't know in advance how many locations a Google account will have, I have no idea how many calls I'll need to make to fetch all information. Each call spawns an asynchronous callback function and I have no idea in what order these callbacks will be called. As far as I understand, there is no guarantee that asynchronous callbacks will be answered in sequence corresponding to their order of creation.

Here's my basic approach. Each time I create a callback, a global counter is incremented. Each time the callback executes it pushes its response.data into a global array
and decrements the global counter. When the counter falls to zero, that callback handler knows that it is the final callback. It then calls the next step in the processing sequence which aggregates all of the response data from the global array and processes it in bulk.

Code follows. The code operates properly with initial casual testing but I am wondering if what I have done is truly safe from a race-condition which could be caused by multiple callbacks executing simultaneously. Are the operations which I have constructed atomic and thus safe from race conditions? Or do I need to either restructure or explicitly call locking mechanisms in order to safely access my global objects from within the asynchronous callbacks? All the magic happens within -

```
$http.post(url, postData, configHeaders).
    then(function (response) {

        googleResponses.push(response.data);
        googleRequestsOutstanding--;

        if (googleRequestsOutstanding == 0) {
            $scope.viewInsights();
        }
    });
```

Full code below. I am wondering if this is safe. Thank you for your advice!

```
const googleBatchSize = 10;
var googleRequestsOutstanding = 0;
var googleResponses = [];

$scope.batchGoogleRequests = function (url, configHeaders) {

    googleResponses = [];
    var batchIndex = 0;

    var postData = $scope.getPostData();

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.locationsList.length; i++) {

        postData.locationNames.push($scope.locationsList[i].name);
        batchIndex++;

        if (batchIndex == googleBatchSize || i == $scope.locationsList.length - 1) {

            googleRequestsOutstanding++;

            $http.post(url, postData, configHeaders).
                then(function (response) {

                    googleResponses.push(response.data);
                    googleRequestsOutstanding--;

                    if (googleRequestsOutstanding == 0) {
                        $scope.viewInsights();
                    }
                });

            postData = $scope.getPostData();
            batchIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into what you suggest. BTW - full disclosure; I am a complete newbie in javascript. So the technical answer is that I never heard of these things until you mentioned them. ;-) I'll Google around and see what I can find but any additional information or code samples you could point me at will be gratefully accepted!

Comment: You can also try Promise.all, which allows you to give it multiple promises, and it will run when they're all completed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Read [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/). Sequential promises should be chained. Parallel promises should be consolidated with `$q.all`. Avoid using callbacks in promise `.then` methods.

Comment: @JasonSpradlin - Thank you for the reference. This looks like a great way to handle the question of when have all promises completed executing? The other part of my question though, relates to promise concurrency. Is it inherently safe or unsafe to access global variables (either simple variables or arrays) from a promise when other promises may be executing concurrently?